# Infrastructure for Project Using Prism, RIA, EF

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, prism, wcf-ria-services

I want to create an infrastructure for a Silverlight project using Prism, RIA, EF

The main structure of my project is as follow:

Silverlight:

- Infrastructure
- Module A
- Module B
- Shell

Web:

- ServiceA
- ServiseB
- DataService
- MainWebApp

The EF Model Contains in DataService And ServiceA,ServiceB Refrence DataService For Create DomainService Class

ModuleA uses ServiceA as Ria link And ModuleB uses ServiceB as Ria link

ModuleA, ModuleB and shell refrences Infrastructure 
But the main problem is Infrastructure Project

Infrastructure needs EF Entity for Create common interface to Modules

but how Infrastructure project references EF entity?

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand from your problem is you need to have poco entity classes that you can share among your core i.e., Infrastructure and web applications (Silverlight in your case).

**How you do this:**

1. You need to create two libraries; one for core and another for silverlight.
2. Create POCO entities in core library.
3. Add these poco entities as link in your silverlight library.